# sudo not working correctly after some time

Tags: linux, bash, sudo, tty

I have Linux server (CentOS release 6.4) which is able to process source code sent by users. On the server is a Java application which starts a bash script which will run compilation and execution commands of these source codes in a limited way (time and memory are limited, no Internet, executed by limited user).

The Java program must be always be running, so it can register new job requests.
When started, the Java program works fine, but after some time (talking in days), commands are not executed properly. I get the following error message:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

the line which is causing that is:

```
sudo -u codiana $COMMAND &
```

where `$COMMAND` is command to execute along with its arguments

After application restart (kill and start again) everything works.
Is there some time limit on Linux which can cause that?

Comment: This seems related to your issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/111064/sudoers-how-to-disable-requiretty-per-user

Comment: can you share java code?

Comment: look here it will help you http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/195129-sudo-sorry-you-must-have-tty-run-sudo.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions, Unfortunately it will take time to test solutions ;)
Java code is quite simple. I'm using ProcessBuilder, passing List<String> containing command and its arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment /etc/sudoers:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

**Edit:**

```
 man sudoers |  grep requiretty -A 5
   requiretty      If set, sudo will only run when the user is logged in
                   to a real tty.  When this flag is set, sudo can only be
                   run from a login session and not via other means such
                   as cron(8) or cgi-bin scripts.  This flag is off by
                   default.
```

So if this is not desired open /etc/sudoers with you text editor of choice and comment out this line.

Comment: Please explain the answer and the selected command for future reference and to increase the value of your response.